# how to play audio file that i download from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

i wanna make small app that i can download an audiofile and then I play it, well know i can download the audiofile but i can not play it because idk how to acces to that mp3 I tried a lot of time but i end up at the same place that i begin here's ly code :

```
StorageReference storageReference,ref;
    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    CardView MichaelFranzeseBtn;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 MichaelFranzeseBtn = findViewById(R.id.MichaelFranzeseBtn);

        MichaelFranzeseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                download();
            }
        });
  }
public void download(){

        storageReference=firebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        ref=storageReference.child("forest-rain-atmo-fantasy-14435.mp3");
        ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) { String url = uri.toString();
                downloadFiles(MainActivity.this,"forest-rain-atmo-fantasy-14435",".mp3",DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,url);
                //    downloadFile();

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });

    }


    public void downloadFiles(Context context,String fileName,String fileExtension,String destinationDirectory,String url) {

        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,destinationDirectory,fileName+fileExtension);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    }
}
```

Comment: Play a mp3 file is so common. Did you try to research it?

Comment: You asked the download manager to put the file in getExternalFilesDir(). So you might have a look there.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?